# Re-bind Ctrl+number key actions with jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I need to run function if the key combination of Ctrl+[1,...,9] is pressed, but the thing is that at least Google Chrome has its own actions such going on a certain tab binded on these combinations.

Can I overwrite them somehow?

For now I have:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && ($.inArray(e.which,[49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57])!==-1)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do things
    return false;
  }
});
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've put `e.preventDefault();` before `if` statement, and it seems to be working now